# Wordpress the_author_posts_link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a loop where I post list of authors with SQL Query. I also need to post `the_author_posts_link` with links to author pages. When I put it into loop it renders only the 4th entry for every iteration:

```
foreach ($all_users_id as $i_users_id ) :


$user = get_userdata( $i_users_id );

the_author_posts_link();

$email = $user->user_email;
echo $email;
?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the data that gets output?

Comment: The same a href entry for every loop

Answer (score 0):

Why not work with an existing wordpress template tag?: [Template Tags/wp list authors « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors)

**Edit:** Gravatars: [Search WordPress Plugins >> gravatars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=gravatars&sort=)

Comment: Yes, but then I have hard time displaying gravatar images. Any Thoughts on that?